# Why is an async event handler for a jQuery event not getting called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, ecmascript-2017

I'd like to make use of `async/await` with `fetch` in response to my user selecting something from an HTML `<select>` dropdown. To do this, I'm adding an async event handler to the `change` event of the select element:

```
import createDebug from 'debug';
const { onLoad } = require('./util');
const debug = createDebug('data_sources');

onLoad(() => {
  const createParserArgsInputs = async (ev) => {
    debug('hi');
    const $target = $(ev.target);
    const id = $target.val();
    debug($target, id);
    const response = await fetch(`/source-types/${id}/details`);
    const details = await response.json();
    debug(details.parser_args);
  };

  $('#data_source_source_type_id').on('change', createParserArgsInputs);
});
```

`onLoad` is equivalent to `$(document).ready`; all of this is preprocessed by Babel before being sent to the browser.

However, when I select something from the dropdown, I get nothing. No logs; no error messages. The network request, however, *is* fired, and comes back with the expected JSON response - but none of the three logs are logged.

What am I missing? Changing this to a synchronous handler and commenting out the awaits makes the logs appear; is it illegal to have an async function as an event handler?

Comment: jQuery is not going to do anything with the Promise that your function returns to it.

Comment: @Pointy Huh? I'm not returning anything at all, let alone to jQuery.

Comment: No it isnt. Maybe transpiling goes wrong?

Comment: Yes you are. That's what an `async` function means: you're returning a promise with the first `await`.

Comment: Also I'm not sure the second `await` makes sense; that doesn't seem like it'd be an async function (`response.json()`).

Comment: @Pointy .json _is_ async, for some reason. Anyway. I see what you mean about returning a promise, but I don't see where I'm giving it to jQuery.

Comment: @pointy while you are right, your comments are a bit missleading...

Comment: You're passing that `async` function to jQuery as the event handler. The library will call it when the event happens, but it's not expecting a Promise to come back. The jQuery event handler protocol predates the whole Promise thing by some years.

Comment: @JonasW. ?? How? An `async` function returns a Promise, right?

Comment: @Pointy sure, but that shouldn't affect it, unless I'm mistaken. The side-effects of the handler should happen anyway, regardless of what's been returned.

Comment: @ArtOfCode hmmm ... now I see what you mean; let me try a test. (I just got back from a long walk so my brain may be out of sugar.)

Comment: What is that `debug()` thing? This is running in a browser right? Does that do something more/different from `console` APIs?

Comment: @Pointy it's from NPM's `debug` module. This _is_ browser code, but with node module integration via yarn & transpilation by Babel.

Comment: Ah OK. Thanks. Typing in a test now.

Comment: Bah, got it. TL;DR: I'm dumb. Thanks for rubberducking, @Pointy - replacing with `console.log` worked, which made me realise that I hadn't enabled the debug messages -_-

Comment: There are times when I am in fact no more useful than a plastic toy :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is solved and is not part of the questions code